# Will concrete flow up on the outside of form boards?

Tags: concrete, foundation

The trench for our monolithic slab (10' x 20' x 4" slab, 12" wide footer, 18" deep trench) was excavated 3" wider than the planned slab size. Contractor said form boards don't have to go bottom of trench, but concrete company said they should. Concrete company said they usually pour with 4" slump. How low do form boards need to go to keep concrete from flowing up the outside of form boards (blue shaded area on diagram)? I'm not sure if this needs to be formed differently, or if this is maybe handled by pouring footer to bottom of form board first and coming back around (maybe 30 minute delay???) to finish upper part to the top of slab height. (Diagram not to scale.)[image: Trench & Form Board Detail]

@Ecnerwal Are you saying to use 1" and 2" XPS foam together as a 3" spacer below the wooden form board, with one foam board outside the stakes and the other inside? I can see that the outer trench wall would provide needed support (and I could potentially run the outer foam piece above the bottom of the wood form), but how would I keep the inside one from falling in with contractors working hard to place the concrete? I've added two diagrams to depict what I think you are saying (second one with bevel). Seems like the foam also solves the potential problem of not being able to pull stakes out before the concrete sets. I had read about putting pipe insulation around the stakes for that purpose.[image]
[image]

Comment: Concrete costs money.  You do not want it going where not needed/wanted.  Not sure sure how much it will rise, but three inches by maybe 60ft will add up.

Comment: I don't know much about concrete. But wait 30 minutes to pour second part? **No way!** If it is too little time (as I suspect) you will just get a mess and still have leakage through the gap. If it is too much time then you'll have poor bonding between the two batches. Plus it will cost extra - truck runs are timed so now you've gone from one truck run to two (or for a large pour 'n' to '2n'). Just put in some larger boards/forms and you're done.

Comment: How is the contractor planning to remove the stakes holding the form in place once the footer is poured? Are they planning to leave them to rust and eventually break the footer?

Comment: @spuck No he said there is a time frame in which to pull the stakes before concrete is fully set.

Comment: I don't understand why you aren't simply trenching and using the wall of the trench as your below-grade form and the board as the above-grade form.

Comment: @Huesmann The trench was dug 3" wider than the footprint of the slab on all sides. So form boards have to be between inside and outside wall of trench. I was just asking how far below grade form boards need to go--whether they need to go all the way to the bottom of the trench or if they can "float" above the bottom of the trench.  I just don't know how concrete flows. Contractor said he will get them to start with a 2" slump (not 4" like concrete company told me)  and it won't flow up at all on the outside the form board.

Answer (score 2):

Believe the concrete company. Concrete  is heavy, so a little depth causes a great deal of pressure. Form blow-outs are miserable.

I'd look at throwing some 2" and 1" XPS foam sheets down there (unless you can actually lay hands on 3" ones) to fill the space before the pour. Costs less than the concrete you'd be wasting, provides some limited thermal benefit to the slab - more if you extend it to the top after the form boards are off. Or, foam same thickness as form boards, then pack dirt/sand behind to hold it.

I suppose you could potentially get cute and bevel cut foam to flare the bottom, then pack dirt behind it, but I assume that the foundation is large enough as designed, so you don't need more width at the bottom.

*...And since you are pre-pouring, make sure there's an Ufer ground (concrete encased electrode) incorporated. It's as simple as tying the reinforcing steel that may already be there together well (or putting at least 20 feet in) and extending a 1/2" or larger rod up to where it can be connected to the Grounding Electrode System - just make sure nobody cuts that "inconvenient" rod sticking up off. Best ground very little additional money can buy, any time your pour concrete...*